# Structuremap - setup dependency which has dependency

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, nullreferenceexception, structuremap

I'm using structure map as my IOC with web api and I have an injected dependency in my controller and it's concrete type also has a dependecy.

**Controller**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : BaseApiController
{

    //private readonly ProductRepository _manageProducts;
    private readonly IProductFactory _productFactory;
    private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;

    public ProductsController(IProductFactory productFactory, IGenericRepository genericRepository)
    {
        _productFactory = productFactory;
        _genericRepository = genericRepository;
        //_manageProducts = new ProductRepository();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [Route("addProduct")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddNewProduct(ProductViewModels.AddProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {

            _productFactory.CreateProduct(product);
            return Ok("Product Successfully Added");
        }
        return BadRequest("Your must have Administrator rights to perform the operation.");
    }
}
```

**Factory**

```
public class ProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;

    public ProductFactory(IGenericRepository genericRepository)
    {
        _genericRepository = genericRepository;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the product.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The product.</returns>
    /// <param name="viewModel">New product.</param>
    public Product CreateProduct(ProductViewModels.AddProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var productToBeAdded = new Product
        {
            Title = viewModel.Title,
            ISBN = viewModel.ISBN,
        };
        return productToBeAdded;
    }
}
```

When I try to call product controller addproducts I get this runtime error for null reference exception:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
  "StackTrace": "   at ICEBookshop.API.Factories.ProductFactory.CreateProduct(AddProductViewModel viewModel) in C:\\Users\\GOWDY_N\\Source\\Repos\\ICEBookshop.API\\ICEBookshop.API\\P00603ClientApi\\Factories\\ProductFactory.cs:line 29\r\n   at ICEBookshop.API.Controllers.ProductsController.AddNewProduct(AddProductViewModel product) in C:\\Users\\GOWDY_N\\Source\\Repos\\ICEBookshop.API\\ICEBookshop.API\\P00603ClientApi\\Controllers\\ProductsController.cs:line 95\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

**This is what I've done with structuremap**

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public DefaultRegistry()
    {
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        For<IGenericRepository>().Use<GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext>>();
        For<IProductFactory>()
            .Use<ProductFactory>()
            .Ctor<IGenericRepository>()
            .Is<GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext>>().Named("DefaultInstanceKey");


        #endregion
    }
}
```

I thought this would fix it so it knows how to resolve my factory:

```
 For<IProductFactory>()
                    .Use<ProductFactory>()
                    .Ctor<IGenericRepository>()
                    .Is<GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext>>().Named("DefaultInstanceKey");
```

But it doesn't work neither. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just register the two interfaces and their implementations. The framework will resolve the dependencies when resolving the target.

```
For<IGenericRepository>().Use<GenericRepository<ApplicationDbContext>>();
For<IProductFactory>().Use<ProductFactory>();
```